# Downloading multiple pdfs in Python

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, python-requests

I have scraped a list of pdf links (as in the url to them) from a website and saved them in a txt document. I have checked and they are a string. Now I need to actually download them all. 
My code works in Jupyter Notebook but when I try to open the PDF it opens internet explorer then says 'couldn't open PDF'.

I know this works on a single pdf link (without the str() around the filename/data) but how do I get it to work with multiple links?

This is my code:

```
with open('minutelinks.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

urls = (str(data))
import requests 
r = requests.get(urls)

with open("gmcaminutes.pdf", "wb") as code:
    code.write(r.content)
```

It saves the pdf but then can't open it.

I would ideally like one PDF with all of the downloaded PDFs from the string. 
Thanks

Comment: sounds like `code.write` does not produce a properly formatted PDF file. what does the ouput of `file gmcaminutes.pdf` say the file type is?

Comment: @NathanMcCoy PDF File

Comment: try fith PdfFileMerger to merge pdf files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import requests
urls = ['https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tutorial.pdf', "https://www.guru99.com/pdf/c_programming_preview.pdf"]

merger = PdfFileMerger()
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    title = url.split("/")[-1]
    with open(title, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
    merger.append(title)

merger.write("result.pdf")
merger.close()
```

Comment: This works for the examples you've given but not for my 'data'. Any suggestions?

Comment: Update - I think I've found the problem - my links in my 'data' file did not end in .pdf so I've updated my previous scripts that grabbed them to make them end in .pdf which should hopefully work now